# Swift - How to disable a button after being clicked 3 times in a row?

Tags: swift, xcode6

I have a button in a viewcontroller. I need to make it so the button is disabled if clicked 3 times in a row. Then if the user clicks on any other button (or meets another condition), the button should be enabled again.

Comment: [ask], http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a counter to check how many times it was checked in a row

```
var counter: Int
@IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!

@IBAction func otherButtonTouched(sender: UIButton!) {
    self.counter = 0
    self.button1.enable = true
}

@IBAction func button1Touched(sender: UIButton!) {
    self.counter++;
    if (self.counter == 3) {
        sender.enable = false
    }
}
```

Function `button1Touched` is touch inside handler for the button you want to detect 3 touches in a row. Function `otherButtonTouched` is handler for any other button that resets the counter and enable the button.